# Automating Xamarin ToolbarItem click

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I'm using Xamarin.UITest to write some automation.
The target app has this in its markup:

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="Settings" AutomationId="SettingsToolbarItem" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Command="{Binding ShowSettingsCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

So far I've had 3 approaches:

Using .Class and Indexing successfully finds the element

```
systemMenuButton = x => x.Class("android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView").Index(1);
```

Using .Property fails to find the element

```
systemMenuButton = e => e.Property("Command", "ShowSettingsCommand");
```

Similarly, using .Marked also fails to find the element

```
systemMenuButton = x => x.Marked("SettingsToolbarItem");
```

Relevant automation code is as follows:

```
using Query = System.Func<Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery, Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery>;
....
protected readonly Query systemMenuButton = x => x.Marked("SettingsToolbarItem");
....
app.Tap(systemMenuButton);
```

I get a generic "unable to find element" exception:

> Unable to find element. Query for Marked("SettingsToolbarItem") gave no results.

I don't get this exception when clicking on other elements outside the ContentPage.ToolbarItems block on the same View/Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've hit the same problem - for some reason Android can't detect `ToolbarItem.AutomationId`.

A workaround is to assign `ToolbarItem.Text` the same value as `ToolbarItem.AutomationId`.

#### Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage

```xml
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Icon="Settings" Text="SettingsToolbarItem" AutomationId="SettingsToolbarItem" Order="Primary" Priority="1" Command="{Binding ShowSettingsCommand}" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

#### Xamarin.UITest

```
using Query = System.Func<Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery, Xamarin.UITest.Queries.AppQuery>;
// ....
protected readonly Query systemMenuButton = x => x.Marked("SettingsToolbarItem");
//....

public void TapSystemMenuButton()
{
    app.Tap(systemMenuButton);

    app.Screenshot("Tapped System Menu Button");
}
```

Here's is a sample app where I use similar logic to tap a ToolbarItem in a UITest: https://github.com/brminnick/InvestmentDataSampleApp/

#### Edit

In the comments, you mentioned that you do not have access to the source code of the Xamarin.Forms app.

If you are unable to change the Xamarin.Forms source code, you will have to use `x => x.Class("ActionMenuItemView").Index(1)`.

I don't recommend going this route because the int parameter of `Index` can vary depending on the device; it is not guaranteed to always be `1`.

```
public void TapSystemMenuButton()
{
    if (app is iOSApp)
        app.Tap(systemMenuButton);
    else
        app.Tap(x => x.Class("ActionMenuItemView").Index(1));

    app.Screenshot("Tapped System Menu Button");
}
```

Comment: is there a way to differentiate between multiple icons without indexing? i already use class and its not my preferred solution

Comment: Yup - there's a workaround. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer and the corresponding sample app to include this workaround 

Comment: Does the text you added to the ToolbarItem display in the toolbar? what if i dont have access or cannot change certain aspects of the sourcecode

Comment: The text will not appear because you are using an Icon. If you can't change the source code, you will need to use `app.Tap(x => x.Class("ActionMenuItemView").Index(1));`. I recommend working with the development team to add this to the source code because the int parameter of `.Index()` is not guaranteed to always be the same, and if/when it changes your tests will fail.

Comment: lemme test this out monday and ill get back with you if it doesnt play out. thanks!!